# Atom doesnt work on Ubuntu on Wayland

Tags: atom-editor, ubuntu-18.04, wayland

I’m using Ubuntu on Wayland because of other apps, which doesn’t work on ubuntu, But when i start atom (even form menu or from terminal) the system suspends, and i have to log in again. In normal Ubuntu it works perfectly. Do you know the solution? I tried to reinstall atom, and instaled libgconf-2-4 as was suggested, but did not work.

Thank you

Comment: I run Atom-editor on Ubuntu 18.04 with Wayland just fine, so the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions on coding. I'd post this on https://askubuntu.com/ instead!